# Jquery Datatables Paging for transposed tables

Tags: datatables, transpose

I'm using **jquery datatables** for my web app. On a particular page I have a to show data in a transposed fashion with column headers on the extreme left.

Is there a possiblity to use datatables here and add a paging functionality to this table.I have tried `$('#characters').dataTable();` but this doesn't seem to work as I do not have any `<thead>` tags in my HTML table.

Here is my Java-script code I use to transpose:

```
    function transpose() {
                var t = $('#characters tbody').eq(0);
                var r = t.find('tr');
                var cols = r.length;
                var rows = r.eq(0).find('td').length;
                var cell, next, tem, i = 0;
                var tb = $('<tbody></tbody>');

                while (i < rows) {
                    cell = 0;
                    tem = $('<tr></tr>');
                    while (cell < cols) {
                        next = r.eq(cell++).find('td').eq(0);
                        tem.append(next);
                    }
                    tb.append(tem);
                    ++i;
                }
                $('#characters').append(tb);
                $('#characters').show();
            }
```

This is my HTML table in which I dynamically generate data:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="characters">
                    <tbody>                    
                    </tbody>
    </table>
```